impersonate wallet address in browser
I'm looking for a way to emulate a wallet address in browser for solana dApps. Similar to https://impersonator.xyz/
The goal is to interact with Solana dApps as a wallet address without holding that addresses private keys. I understand I won't be able to sign any transactions but I would like to the dApps to read state for arbitrary accounts without importing private keys to untrusted devices f.x.

It's a good question, it doesn't seem like there's a wallet like that for Solana yet

I have not used this, but I saw it on GitHub the other day--it might be helpful as well: https://github.com/TeamRaccoons/sherlock-wallet

I've built an open source read-only wallet that can be used for this called Orbit. It's not primarily built for this, but you can add any address. Most dapps will detect it and allow you to connect using it.
Github: https://github.com/mcintyre94/Orbit
Chrome extension store (free): https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/orbit/amnodpohcllgfbhgoephohmhlfgichfa
